# Receiver of ActiveMQ: not able to retrieve whats in the Queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have executed the hello world program as mentioned in the below link.. http://www.coderpanda.com/jms-example-using-apache-activemq/ Also, I have downloaded the ActiveMQ jar and related files as mentioned. I am able to compile and run the all the java files too. Noticed that the receiver java file compiles successfully but when the Receiver executes no output message gets generated on the console. The message sent to the queue is not getting retrieved. I can see that message count getting increased on UI of ActiveMQ  on each hit(hosted on local host url) but the message put on the queue is not yet printed/retrieved. Can anyone suggest any other implementation for  publisher subscriber, if any? Or your thoughts on JMS Q...

Comment: check in ActiveMQ UI , if for the queue on which messages are increasing has an consumer attached i.e. the 'no of consumers' column, if it shows 0 when receiver is running, then it means your receiver is listening to wrong queue. If so check for a queue which has no of consumers greater than 0 , that might be the queue on which your receiver is listening

Comment: when i first run the Sender.java Class -->Name=SAMPLEQUEUE            Number Of Pending Messages=0   Number Of Consumers=2   Messages Enqueued=1   Messages Dequeued=1

Comment: when I run the Receiver.java now then this is the status in ActiveMQ console
Name=SAMPLEQUEUE  Number Of Pending Messages=0   Number Of Consumers=3   Messages Enqueued=1   Messages Dequeued=1

Comment: How do I knw the receiver is listening to the wrong queue? Can that be seen through UI of ActiveMQ? if yes, How? as you can see I have entitled "SAMPLEQUEUE" as the queue name. And when i debug at this point "Message message = consumer.receive(); " the debug bar vanishes... seems like it is stuck at receive() function... any idea??

Comment: When you see a message dequed count increasing, then it is clear that message is successfully consumed by some consumer, and on  running of your receiver, why did your consumer count increase in queue? Are there multiple instances? Or you haven't closed the connection properly

Comment: Below is the status when Sender.java is executed once and only once.. that opens a Persistent  connection... as below...
-->Browse SAMPLEQUEUE
Message ID   Correlation ID   Persistence   Priority   Redelivered   Reply To   Timestamp   Type   Operations   
ID:ComputerName-57663-1436338542183-1:1:1:1:1  Persistent  4 false  2015-07-08 12:25:42:553 IST   Delete  
---------------------these are the --->Topics
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection 0 2 0 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.SAMPLEQUEUE 0 4 0 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.MasterBroker 0 1 0 Send To Active 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.SAMPLEQUEUE 0 1 0

Comment: these are the --->Topics
Name ↑ Number Of Consumers   Messages Enqueued   Messages Dequeued   Operations   
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection 0 2 0 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.SAMPLEQUEUE 0 4 0 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.MasterBroker 0 1 0 Send To Active 
ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.SAMPLEQUEUE 0 1 0

Comment: OK this time Reciver ran as expected.. maybe it was too may timesthe message being concumed. Thanks Vihar..Name   Remote Address   Active   Slow   
ID:ComputerName-57663-1436338542183-0:1 tcp://127.0.0.1:57664 true false 
--->Queues
Name   NoPendingMessages   NoOfCosmrs   MsgEq   Msg Dq   Vw   
SAMPLEQUEUE 1 0 1 0 Browse Active---------------------------------------------->   Name   Number Of Pending Messages   Number Of Consumers   Messages Enqueued   Messages Dequeued   Views   Operations   
SAMPLEQUEUE 0 1 1 1 Browse Active Consumers
Active Producers
   Send To Purge Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Vihar is right.

> When you see a message dequed count increasing, then it is clear that message is successfully consumed by some consumer, and on  running of your receiver, why did your consumer count increase in queue? Are there multiple instances? Or you haven't closed the connection properly

I did not close the connection and consumers consumed the message in the queue whtn I ran the receive multiple times, I had no clue why and how it happened not until I ran it one at a time keeping a tab at the queue at the same time.